# Python np.fromfile gives Error: Errno 2 No such file or directory

Tags: python, numpy

I ran the following code And I saw the output.

```
 file_path='C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Downloads\\Data\\A01AP\\N2001A01AP61.bin'
 def read_file():
    data=np.fromfile(file_path,np.float64)
    print(data)
    return data
```

But when I gave the new path for the second time,I got the following error:

(no such file or directory )
what's the problem?

Comment: Kindly check the formatting and tags you have applied to your question. Thank you.

Comment: We will need a bit more, to help you. What is the second input for the new path? How do you call it? Does the file really exists? Etc.

Comment: @Minarth The second input is exactly the same as the first one, only it has a different address and Yes there is data in the given address

Comment: Still don't know, how do you call it. How do you run your code? Both runs, the working one and the failing one? If the second input is exactly the same as the first one, only it has different address, the input is different.

Comment: @Minarth I give the input address only.Exactly the previous data just with a different address